# jQuery in Angular 6 magnificPopup not a function

Tags: jquery, angular6, magnific-popup

I am trying to use jQuery **magnificPopup** and getting error in console.

> $(...).magnificPopup is not a function

I am including this:

> "scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]

in angular.json file and my controller looks like this:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.less'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor() {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        debugger;
        $('#inline-popups').magnificPopup({ // says magnificPopup is not a function
            delegate: 'a',
            removalDelay: 500,
            callbacks: {
            beforeOpen: function() {
                    this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
                }
            },
            midClick: true
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad... Have forgotten to include cdn 
**https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js**

Comment: where you had use this
 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js